# Is this the proper use of ThreadLocal<T>?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-local

All examples I've seen return a magic number or a literal String which isn't of much use. If I want to store a non-threadsafe object in ThreadLocal, is this correct?

```
private ThreadLocal<Bar> threadLocal= new ThreadLocal<Bar>( () =>  new Bar() ); 
public void Foo()
{
  Bar myBar = threadLocal.Value;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a `ThreadLocal` for a *local* variable? Only one thread is going to be using that local variable anyway. (Or if you use it in an async method, you'll get some pretty confusing results...)

Comment: I guess his examples should be that he stores `myBar` in a field or property, and `threadLocal` alters the state of the object.

Comment: My bad, I foobard up the examples. Will fix

Comment: Fixed example to actually make some sense. Teaches me to post a question before running off to lunch.

Comment: It is still not clear what you are asking. All `ThreadLocal<T>` does is store a single value per thread. That value can indeed be a reference to a class instance (a `string` reference is in fact a reference to a class instance, so even the example you say you've seen seems to apply here). Using `ThreadLocal<T>` can _help_ ensure you use a not-thread-safe object only in one thread, but it can't guarantee it; you could still write code somewhere that passed the object from one thread to another.

Comment: Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what _specific_ problem you are trying to solve and explain in precise terms what specific difficulty you are having while trying to solve that problem.